# Error: Invalid Value (Sequelize date format) on query in where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Using mysql in where clause gives me invalid error, my model is

```
Error: Invalid value { created_at: { [Symbol(gte)]: '2022-12-31T00:00:00.000Z' } }
```

```
Job.init({},{sequelize, tableName: 'jobs', timestamps: false, modelName: 'Job'});
```

Query used for this

```
Job.findAll({
    ....
    ....
    where: {
        created_at: {
            [Op.gte]: '2022-12-31T00:00:00.000Z'
        }
    }
})
```

Used the following as well

```
Job.findAll({
    ....
    ....
    where: {
        created_at: {
            [Op.gte]: '2022-12-31 00:00:00'
        }
    }
})
```

i want to get all details by passed date but not able to do so

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You turned `timestamps` off and trying to add a condition on `created_at` column. Either define `created_at` explicitly in the model or turn on the `timestamps` option and indicate `createdAt: 'created_at'`

Comment: @Anatoly created_at is defined in the table explicitly

Comment: Ok, but Sequelize stiil has to know about it unbtil you use raw SQL query